# Please help, Prove Using Arithmetic Mean - Geometric Mean

Tags: real-numbers

Please help!! 
PROVE THAT f(x) = 2(1-x)(1+x) 1+x) ≤ 64/27 . and reaches maximum value for x ∈[0,1] off x=1/3

Can anyone tell me what the steps are, I just keep getting 4=4 whenever I try to solve it!

Comment: @arberavdullahu I'm getting stuck, it comes to 4=4 can you please help? It'll be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use AM-GM for $2-2x,1+x,1+x$(we can use it because all of them are non negative) you get that $$\frac{2-2x+1+x+1+x}{3}\geq \sqrt[3]{(2-2x)(1+x)(1+x)}$$ or
$$\frac{4}{3}\geq \sqrt[3]{(2-2x)(1+x)(1+x)}$$
getting ride of cube we get that
$$\frac{64}{27}=(\frac{4}{3})^3\geq (2-2x)(1+x)(1+x)$$
So $$2(1-1x)(1+x)(1+x)\leq \frac{64}{27}$$
Also it reaches maximum in case of equality i.e. $2-2x=1+x$ so $x=\frac{1}{3}$ 

Let me know if you don't get any part of it.

Comment: Wow thank you, just one question how do we know that they are non negative?

Comment: By substituting 1 in place of x?

Comment: You are welcome. Yeah basically you look it's minimum for example for 2-2x minimum is when x is maximum so x=1 then minimum of 2-2x = 0, similiar for 1+x

Comment: okay thank you so much for helping me! Thank you very very much!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: how do I prove that it reaches maximum value for x belonging to [0,1] off x=1/3, I mean how to write it exactly? Sorry for asking too much

Comment: do I have to substitute x=1/3 ?

Comment: I got it I got thank you

Comment: Hey can you please help me with a question I just asked , whenever you are free